# Json object with attributes + array, how to move the attributes inside the array?

Tags: javascript, json

Is there a way to achieve this json transformation  using javascript ?

**input**

```
{
"server":"S1",
"timestamp":"123456",
"data":[
        {"device":"D1", "price":"50"},
        {"device":"D2", "price":"60"},
        {"device":"D3", "price":"70"}
     ]
}
```

**output**

```
{
"data":[
     {"server":"S1", "timestamp":"123456", "device":"D1", "price":"50"},
     {"server":"S1", "timestamp":"123456", "device":"D2", "price":"60"},
     {"server":"S1", "timestamp":"123456", "device":"D3", "price":"70"}
]
}
```

Comment: what did you done so far ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this:

```js
const data  = {
"server":"S1",
"timestamp":"123456",
"data":[
        {"device":"D1", "price":"50"},
        {"device":"D2", "price":"60"},
        {"device":"D3", "price":"70"}
     ]
}


result = {data: data.data.map(res=>({...res, ...{'timestamp': data.timestamp, 'server': data.server} }))}

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Let us say your input object is

```
var input = {
"server":"S1",
"timestamp":"123456",
"data":[
    {"device":"D1", "price":"50"},
    {"device":"D2", "price":"60"},
    {"device":"D3", "price":"70"}
 ]
  }
```

You can convert to expected output as,

```
let output = {
data:[]
 }

input.data.forEach(transformfunction);

function transformfunction(value,index,array){

  output.data.push(
             {
             "server":input.server,
             "timestamp":input.timestamp,
              "device":array[index].device,
              "price":array[index].price
          }
      );

  }

  console.log(JSON.stringify(output));
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: This answer will work in all browsers that I am not using any of ES6 features !